Advantages of a military comprised of duplicants
Although the members of this military are genetically identical, don't think of it as a clone army. "Clone army" implies its members are merely genetic copies of one another. In actuality, it's more like Calvin's duplicator: they're both physical/genetic and mental copies of one another. Here is how the process works.
The proteome of a human is sequenced. Their brain is then scanned down to the level of the internal geometry of individual brain cells, a process which invariably kills the subject. Using the proteome for reference, microscopic limbs assemble near-physically identical copies of the individual's body. On hand for this procedure are an equal number of artificial brains designed to emulate natural brains (although they operate by very different mechanisms). Data derived from the scan of the original brain is reformatted into something the artificial brains can understand, then downloaded into them. The brains are then installed into the duplicated bodies and booted on via laser. Congratulations — you have duplicants.
An in-setting convention is that, provided one copy of a person survives while the other copies of that person know that first copy will, the other copies fear death far less than they otherwise would. Therefore, the duplicants are usually "recycled" at standardized intervals: all but one have their artificial brains wiped and their mindless bodies broken down for biomass. This biomass is used, alongside the original proteome, to assemble another set of bodies, which copies of the surviving duplicant are then downloaded into. In this way duplicants can still learn and grow as individuals while simultaneously being immortal; any damage to their bodies is soon erased but the best version of themself lives on as long as they want to. This is a military advantage which isn't immediately obvious from reading the question and which I therefore wouldn't expect an answer to come up with without knowing more about the setting: duplicant military personnel don't fear death, just pain.
This question isn't intended to "farm for ideas". I believe there are tangible, objective, non-opinion-based military benefits to a military whose members are mostly/all duplicants, and have already thought of several examples:

Duplicants are the same shape as other duplicants made from the same template, meaning their clothes and armor can be the same size, ergonomic chairs and cockpits can be built to fit specifically them, etc.
Duplicants share the same blood type, health problems, dietary limitations, etc. meaning medical care can easily be standardized
Duplicants lack infighting, insubordination, personality conflicts relative to conventional militaries, as all of them are the same personality, give or take a year of independent development.
Ideally, the originals lack relationships with other people. After all, if you duplicate a lady with a family and friends 10,000 times, that means 10,000 people have those relationships with only 1 set of family and friends to go around, and that's bad for duplicant (and family) mental health. This makes the duplicant amenable to military social organization, which offers them a purpose.
Casualties aren't as politically problematic as with conventional militaries, because it's a single individual doing the dying — who's technically not even dying, either.
Training costs are far lower. Instead of training 100,000 different people fairly well, you can focus your entire educational regimen on training 1 person incredibly well and then hitting CTRL-C + CTRL-V 100,000 times.
Speciality roles. There can be one specialized duplicant who's all the cyberwarfare specialists in the military, one specialized duplicant who's all the medics in the military, one specialized duplicant who's all the submariners in the military, etc. Obviously some level of generalization is required but for specialist roles it's a great way to ensure you have the best specialists possible (see bullet point immediately prior).

The technology required to make more duplication units has long since been lost. As nobody in-setting understands how it works (other than that it does), there's no need for anyone outside the setting to, either. Most technology in this setting is 21st-century level, including military science. With this in mind, what are other military advantages of this sort of duplicant army?

I am not sure why you would believe that a complete lack of diversity is a good thing. In a normal army you want to have some risk takers, you want to have some risk avoiders, you want some who think outside the box, you want some who always color within the lines, you want some big strong brutes, you want some short thin tricksters, you want some who volunteer, you want some who never volunteer, you want some dashing daredevils, you want some who move only after careful consideration, some cold blooded sharpshooters, some hot blooded brawlers, some who flash brighly, some who smoulder slowly.

@AlexP The duplicants don't necessarily need to all of one person. If needed, there can be, say, 100 separate infantry "strains", 10 tank operator ones, etc. 10 different pilots, etc. Even with such numbers it'd still hold advantages over a military where everyone is an individual. Additionally, the interval between "recyclings" can be extended to some extent so individual duplicants can diverge from the original somewhat.

Are you only looking for advantages?  You seem to have hit them already (though probably overstated) and there are numerous, huge disadvantages.

[help]: Avoid asking questions where your answer is provided along with the question, and you expect more answers.

@KerrAvon2055 I'm only looking for advantages. It's supposed to be a bad idea overall, but it doesn't make sense for someone in-setting to adopt a bad idea unless it seems like a good one on the face of things.

@L.Dutch The sense the help center uses that phrase in is “I use ______ for ______, what do you use?” In this case, I'm not asking that, but instead providing examples of the sort of answers I'm looking for, so as to prove this question is answerable.

I don't think this is possible with 21st-century tech. You might want to have it in the future a bit, since we can't do the kind of mental cloning you are describing,now or anytime soon, at even a small scale.

@Bubbles I specifically pointed out that it's lost technology nobody in-setting knows how to manufacture anymore — otherwise, people in-setting would have to know how it works and that's harder to write.

"Duplicants lack infighting, insubordination, personality conflicts relative to conventional militaries, as all of them are the same personality" I call BS on this one. Lots of people that exist that couldn't live with a duplicate of tehmselves..

@ KEY_ABRADE Must have missed that. But the technology in the duplication units itself is probably still more valuable than the ability to make more duplicates, so why hasn't one been taken apart? if it's because it's functionally indestructible, why is that so? And the material can till be analyzed, eventually, someone will get in. So it just doesn't really make sense to use those units for making duplicates.

Diversity in the armies is only necessary due to general inefficiency and poor quality of the conscripts. A Jack of All Trades soldier who is already optimal for the job, all the jobs, in fact, need not be so diverse. Diversity fo thought can be achieved by non-duplicant high command.

Frame Challenge: Most of your listed advantages are actually disadvantages
Fear of Death: Your duplicants will still fear death because fear of death is as much a genetic trait as it is learned. A lot of people still fear snakes and spiders, even when they know they are dealing with non-venomous varieties.  Also, because thier cybernetic brains can still be destroyed, there is still the risk of brain death.  Also, there is the very real metaphysical debate about whether it is murder to scrub an artificial brain. Most humans would not feel any better about death if you told them that there is an identical version of them waiting around to replace them; so, your practice of brain recycling will likely lead to uprisings.  Furthermore, continued exposure to violence results in PTSD, if you keep copying the same seasoned war veteran over and over along with all of his experiences of death and killing and seeing his friends die off from head shots etc. Then eventually the consciousness will become so traumatized that the person will become unwilling or unable to continue to function as a soldier.
Same Genetics: While this makes standardized care easier, it also makes it easier for the enemy to formulate standardized and highly targeted bioweapons.  If your replicant has a peanut allergy, then the enemy could spray the battlefield with Ara H proteins instead of minefields allowing thier soldiers to pass harmlessly though an environment that they've made fatal to the duplicants.
Personality Conflicts: Most people do not get along any better with people of the same personality as they do with people who have different personalities.  Especially in an organized power structure like the military.  A person with a strong sense of devotion when partnered with someone who is more decisive will tend to function better together than two decisive people who will want to argue over who is right or two devoted people will always look to each other to make decisions causing them to get stuck hesitating waiting for guidance.  There is also the issue of confirmation bias.  When two different people examine a problem and come to the same solution, it's usually the right choice, but when two identical people come to the same conclusion, instead of being each other's check and balance system, it means they will confirm each other's false conclusions increasing thier confidence that they are correct anyway.
Focus your entire educational regimen on training 1 person incredibly well: If you know your enemy's military doctrine, you automatically have a huge advantage against them, no matter how good that doctrine is in theory.  The problem here is that your duplicants will all make the same sorts of tactical choices.  They will advance, retreat, and entrap by using the exact same training information.  This means that your army will become extremely predictable; so, even if that good training pays off in the opening days of a war, your habits will become evident very quickly making it easy for the enemy to lead your men into traps and otherwise manipulate your actions at a strategic scale.
Actual Advantages
The only real advantages you've listed so far is lower training costs, less political concerns over casualties (people love to not care about anyone that they can internalize as less than human), and standardized body shapes.  However, these 3 advantages culminate to one big meta advantage which is numerical superiority.
Individually, duplicants are actually worse soldiers than having a mentally and genetically diverse military, but fielding a whole lot of duplicants becomes way easier than trying to recruit and train the same number of troops.  Economy of scale and standardization makes them cheaper to equip.  Being able to duplicate training means that causalities can be quickly replaced without having to wait the 6-24 months it normally takes to train a new soldier.  And the big kicker, you never need to start a draft because of lack of volunteers to join your army because you can just ramp up your cloning of the same few gungho recruits.  So, although your army will almost certainly underperform against thier enemies in the body count department, they can afford a level of attrition that the enemy can not.
The Best Way to maximize thier effectiveness
Make each unit a mixed bag: Although a unit of 12 identical infantry guys is predictable, if your have 20 or 30 infantry duplicants that you can randomly mix and match, then you can still create a lot of randomization in the way that your units will collectively learn to work together.  This will minimize issues with Same Genetics, Personality Conflicts, and focused training without completely abandoning the benefits of each.
Next, all of your units should have some level of post cloning training before being sent to the front line.  This training will be vital to make sure that your random selection of duplicants will know how to work well together, plus it gives you the opportunity to observe each team configuration so that you can learn who does and does not pair well together.
Next, you can't recycle a living replicant, at least not the brain part.  This takes away your ability to give them hope for a better future, and a soldier without hope is as useful as a gun without bullets.  If your duplicants believe that they will fight for a while and then retire with full benefits, it gives military command leverage to keep them loyal.  Technically I'm not saying you can't recycle them when done, but they have to believe they have a civilian life to go back to  after the war.
Lastly, you still need to command them with all the same considerations as you would a human soldier.  They still have thier human memories, ideals, and emotions; so, if they feel like you are just sending them to the meat grinder to die, they will rise up just as fast as any other set of humans... possibly faster since they will all be much better at predicting one another making it easier to know when and how to talk about insubordination among themselves.  Also another good reason to make sure that no unit has more than one of the same duplicant.

Just One More, and It Isn't Really Worth It
The only additional advantage a clone army has (provided you have all your "base" humans trained and ready when the war starts) is that you can get your replacements quicker than your opponent in a long war.  It takes 90 days to train an infantryman who is barely competent to do the job, and eventually you run out of combat-age people you can suck from society.  If your clones come out quicker than that and you can make infinite numbers of them, that's an advantage. The other advantages are as you say, standardization in equipment to save money and ease logistical burdens (everyone wears Size 11 shoes and Large uniforms).  There's also a benefit in training the best of the best and hitting "copy/paste" rather than spend time training the weak and instructing the stupid. You still need to pay to maintain that high level of training (look at how much is spent in the US on combat readiness training for veteran infantry or flight time for fighter pilots) but it does save a decent chunk of cash and time.
However several of your listed "advantages" are actually pretty significant drawbacks.  For example:
Same Blood Type/health problems and so on- This means the army would be EXTREMELY susceptible to tailored biological/chemical attacks.  There's even the problem of things like "their natural circadian rhythm would be identical meaning the whole force would be less alert at specific trackable times." Sure you only need one type of blood for the medics, but you'll have way bigger problems.
Your duplicates would be no less (and probably more) likely to suffer from backbiting infighting and insubordination. Would you really want to be a private when the guys with more power (sergeants, captains, generals, however high up the chain your clones go) are EXACTLY YOU? Why are you part of Forlorn Hope 642 and taking orders from Safe in the Rear You instead of the other way around?  Screw that guy!
Even the best soldier in the world isn't good at EVERYTHING.  And I'm not talking about "good infantryman vs good tanker."  I'm talking about the subtle differences in psychology that allow a well-trained squad to spot an ambush ahead of time because one guy naturally looks left more than right or reacts more to light than movement or knows more than average about moving in the woods/a city/whatever.
A lack of relationships is going to be a serious long-term (and probably short-term) problem.  Military formations that have strong internal bonds and no ties to the polity they defend beyond "it's our job" invariably go "why are we doing this?" From there they invariably attempt (and frequently succeed at) overthrowing the government.
Specialty roles fixes some of the above, but you still have the significant problem of "Why am I taking orders from Me" combined with "Why am I forever to be a private/tank gunner/whatever just because I was born Me?"

Between the fact that the Duplicants are a Culture by themselves, separate from the rest of humanity, you have the fact that they can "die and recombine" making each iteration of Duplicants smarter (or at least, more experienced) than the last one.
RIP humanity. There is zero reason Duplicants could not either take over the world (or at least, their former country) or at the very least, effectively replace humans at every point due to being impossibly well trained in everything, and perfectly synchronised. Few iterations in, the Duplicates would be perfect Jacks of All Trades. A few iterations further, every Dupe is now an omnidisciplinary scientist and expert in everything a human can reasonably be expert in.
What is the purpose of regular humies existing then? Dupes are clearly superior in every possible way. Other than as pets/sex slaves/amusement, humans have no longer any value.
